# Appending a 1 on the bottom of MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, math.net

I need to append a `1` on the bottom of an instance of the `Vector` class from `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra` namespace. Any help is appreciated (even suggestions for a different package for linear algebra).

Answer (score 1):

Shortest solution I found:

```
List<double> temp = start.ToList();
temp.Add(1.0);
Vector<double> new = CreateVector.DenseFromEnumerable<double>(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a short way:

```
var vector = new DenseVector(new double[2]);
var extended = DenseVector.OfEnumerable(vector.Append(1));
```